# WPF ComboBox MaxDropDownItems

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Is there anyway to set the maximum number of drop down items rather than the max drop down height in WPF?
Thanks!
-Kevin

Comment: Why don't you just limit the amount you are loading in to the `ComboBox`? Add only up to your max.  What would you expect the control to do when going beyond the max?  Throw an exception?  Just not add it?

Comment: No... Rather than hard  coding max drop down height. I'd rather be able to set the amount of max drop down items to be displayed. Sorry i worded it weirdly, I was thinking of VB's combo boxes where they have a max drop down displayed at once.

Answer (score 12):

This question may only be meaningful if all of your items have the same height.  Otherwise as you scroll your ComboBox up and down to see different portions of the item list your ComboBox would get bigger and smaller as you scroll.

If all of your items *are* the same height, it's very easy to do this using an attached property:

```
public class ComboBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
  public static int GetMaxDropDownItems(DependencyObject obj) { return (int)obj.GetValue(MaxDropDownItemsProperty); }
  public static void SetMaxDropDownItems(DependencyObject obj, int value) { obj.SetValue(MaxDropDownItemsProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxDropDownItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MaxDropDownItems", typeof(int), typeof(ComboBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
    {
      var box = (ComboBox)obj;
      box.DropDownOpened += UpdateHeight;
      if(box.IsDropDownOpen) UpdateHeight(box, null);
    }
  });

  private static void UpdateHeight(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var box = (ComboBox)sender;
    box.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
      {
        var container = box.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as UIElement;
        if(container!=null && container.RenderSize.Height>0)
          box.MaxDropDownHeight = container.RenderSize.Height * GetMaxDropDownItems(box);
      }));
  }
}
```

With this property you can write:

```
<ComboBox ...
   my:ComboBoxHelper.MaxDropDownItems="8" />
```

Comment: I tested this code directly. The XAML doesn't generate an error or anything but when I run the application the combo box list height remains at about 5 items and tried a value of 15.

Comment: There is a jump between sizes visible, when the combobox is first open, I set the DispatcherPriotiry to Normal. And now it works exactly as I need it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to say display X number of items.  You must use the `MaxDropDownHeight` property to limit it's size.  Since this property is no calculated by the control and is full customizable you could write something to calculate an item's height and then multiple that by the max items you want to display and then set `MaxDropDownHeight` based on it.

Comment: +1 Right idea, as long as all the items are the same height. This should probably be done in an attached property.  I'll add an answer that has the actual code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where combobox dropdown won't occupy whole vertical space - I would get vertical scrollbar after 3 to 4 items in spite of having enough vertical space for 20 items. I created a tempList and added comboboxitems to that list. Assigned this tempList to ComboBox's ItemsControl binding, that gave combo box initial dropdown height.
Now combo box could display 20 items without vertical scrollbar.

MaxDropDownHeight didnt work, neither before nor after initializing the view.

Hope it helps someone!

Thanks,

RDV