# Combobox Only show some comboxitems

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Ive set up a `ComboBox` with about 20 `ComboBox items` in it. I wanted to be able to limit the number the user can see when they click a check box e.g

```
if (checkbox1.ischecked)    
{
    combobox1.items = item 1, item 2 // correct code here    
}
```

been searching the web and MSDN etc and i am not even sure if its possible any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Where do you get the items for the combo box from?

Comment: What do you mean limit the number they can see? Do you mean make the viewable area in combobox dropdown smaller? Do you mean only add items into the combobox up to the limit set by the user with checkbox? Can you give us more info on your requirements?

Comment: sorry didnt explain it very well.

Comment: the combo box already has its items set up <ComboBoxItem Content="apples" Name="app1"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="oranges" Name="orng1"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="pears" Name="pear1"/> when they click the check box i want the combobox to only show them "apples" as a selectable itemm

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018267/wpf-combobox-maxdropdownitems also sheridans answer seems to be a simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you will have to decide which items will be added to suit you, but in this example, I'm just picking the first 5 items:

```
if (checkBox1.IsChecked)
{
    ObservableCollection<YourItemType> filteredCollection = originalItemsSource.Take(5);
    comboBox1.ItemsSource = filteredCollection;
}
else comboBox1.ItemsSource = originalItemsSource;
```

Note also that I am assuming that you have set the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to a collection (the full collection) named `originalItemsSource`, which *remains* full and unaltered.

Comment: Based on his comment under the question I think he is adding each item manually in Xaml

Comment: Thanks @Kazuo, I didn't notice that... all the same, he could still store references to his XAML declared items in the `originalItemsSource` parameter in a `Loaded` event (or similar) and then use this code example as is.

Comment: I agree the approach here is to filter a combobox source as per your answer. Left the comment in case the OP did not understand your solution based on your assumption.

Comment: Why not use `CollectionViewSource`? It has Filter event. Which I belive is more appropiate...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the collection, you can simply tweak the visibility, so given this xaml

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="itemsBox">
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="itemRed" Content="Red"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="White"/>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="itemBlue" Content="Blue"/>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Click="checkBox_Click"/>
```

You just need,

```
private void checkBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemBlue.Visibility = checkBox.IsChecked.Value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    itemRed.Visibility = checkBox.IsChecked.Value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

However Sheridan's answer will be far more flexible in the long term as filtering the collections is a far better way to go. If you are trying to do anything other than expose/hide a fixed set of items (note mine above are named explicitly) you really should move to `ItemsSource`

i.e. If you start doing this,

```
private void checkBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var x in new ComboBoxItem[] { ItemBlue, ItemRed /*, etc*/ })
    {
        x.Visibility = checkBox.IsChecked.Value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
     }
 }
```

Then refactor it to an ItemsSource

Comment: Thanks Alski, your way works too, gave sheridan the tick as he as first, thanks for the help tho.

Comment: No, no, give Sheridan the tick because his solution is a better way of doing it, not because he was first ;-)