# wpf autocompletebox default dropdown area is too small

Tags: wpf, autocompletebox

I set the autocompletebox just like this:

```
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Width="120">
                <Label Content="Address"/>
                <Controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="AddressBox" MaxDropDownHeight="300" Populating="Address_Populating"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="120" Margin="40, 0, 0, 0">
                <Label Content="Port"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="PortBox" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="ConnectButton" Content="Connect" Margin="40, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Height="35" Click="ConnectButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

But the max number of items displayed in the dropdown window is only 3. I am sure that the candidate number is larger than 3. I want to increase the number of items which will be displayed in the dropdown window.

For example, i want to show 15 candidateAddress's items. And the dropdown window will be displayed and 3 items will be showed firstly. But I hope it can show 5 items firstly, which means that the display area should be expanded.

The logical code of this control is:

```
    private void Address_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string dirFile = "../../Config/Address.config";

        if (File.Exists(dirFile))
        {
            var candidateAddress = new List<string>();
            string input = null;

            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(dirFile))
            {
                while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    candidateAddress.Add(input);
                }
            }

            AddressBox.ItemsSource = candidateAddress;
            AddressBox.PopulateComplete();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Address.config does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: which toolkit/dll?  you should provide it.

Comment: the website of toolkit is [link](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

Comment: could you provide your code? I have test it and  everything is correct.

Comment: do you mean the logical code? I have provided it. I can run this control correctly. But I want to expand the area of display window.

Comment: it is not a problem of display area.check candidateAddress's items and  the text you inputed. could you show them?

Comment: yes, i can show them. for example, i want to show 15 candidateAddress's items. And the dropdown window will be displayed and 3 items will be showed firstly. But I hope it can show 5 items firstly, which means that the display area should be expanded

Comment: I dont understand even now. for example. candidateAddress（10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23）,if you input '1',then the droplist will show (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),if you input '2',it shows(20,21,22,23),you can set MaxDropDownHeight,but you can't set the number of display item,because it's depend on candidateAddress's items and what's your input.

Comment: yep, the droplist will show (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19). But now when i want to choose specific item such as 19, i have to drag the dropdown button to get it. And i want that i do not have to drag the dropdown button and the item (19) will be showed. More specifically, the area which shows the items can contain more items when you cannot drag the dropdown button.

Comment: you mean you don't want use scrollbar and you want to display more item ? just set MaxDropDownHeight, doesn't it working?

Comment: i mean i want the default display area can contain more items while the scrollbar could be used as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't add a pic to comment. so i add it here.

top pic : MaxDropDownHeight=50

bottom: MaxDropDownHeight=300

you mean like this?

[image]

you can creat a new project:

```
     <Grid>
        <control:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="AddressBox" FontSize="30" MaxDropDownHeight="300"
Populating="Address_Populating" Margin="0,0,0,287.283" />
    </Grid>
```

background code:

```
private void Address_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 10; i < 25; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i);
            }
            AddressBox.ItemsSource = lst;
            AddressBox.PopulateComplete();
        }
```

the reason is found by kylejan:
i found the reason. the display area will be influenced by the former window. for example, the window i put this control on is opend by the main window. then this autocomplete box will be influenced by the size of the main window

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way (included in the Framework) to exactly set the number of items to be displayed. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018267/wpf-combobox-maxdropdownitems) example gives you some code to create an attached property that manipulates the maxheight property in order to display any specified number of items.

Comment: thx a lot! i have found the reason which influences the size of area

Comment: You know you then have to mark this answer as the solution?! ;)